# Code Combat Helping edit their code

Tags: code-combat

How do I get to access the level editor feature for code combat particularly for submitting a patch to the language section?

I soon realized, however, that the instructions had yet to be translated from Python to Clojure.

This game is similar to untrusted, which is why I included the tag [untrusted] until codecombat has a tag of its own.

They provide these instructions for editing but I was confused by them.

```
;; If you want to help translate the sample code to Clojure, please!
;; http://codecombat.com/editor/level/sarven-savior
;; Double-click Hero Placeholder, select Programmable - programmableMethods - plan - languages - clojure.
;; You can submit a patch.
```

Has anyone successfully done this in the game, before? I'm a little new to the idea of coding in general, and it's very intimidating. However, this question is about the *editor function* in the game, and how to access it.

Has anyone else run into this problem while playing?

Is there any way I can make this question more specific?

Awaiting help, derogatory put downs of my intellect, or both.

Comment: If you have a question about gameplay, post it here on Arqade. However, since this question is about the coding in the game, please post it over at StackOverflow. See [this post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10527/should-questions-about-screeps-go-to-arqade-or-stack-overflow?cb=1) for a similar game for details.

Comment: // , Coding is a gameplay element, here. He's not asking about *what* to code, only *how* to access the interface in such a way that he can use that game feature. I have seen too many questions like this booted on StackOverflow because they "refer to a program's features", instead of how to actually code.

Comment: @37coins Sorry, this post is really hard to understand at the moment. I have posted a link to the relevant meta discussion for details.

Comment: // , I actually advised this user to avoid the peremptory downvotes that usually come when players new to the process post such questions to stackexchange sites. Isn't this sort of the equivalent of looking for a save or edit button in a level editor for another kind of game?

Comment: // , Edited post for clarity of intent and justification of relevance.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out how to make this work on my own.

Go to the site that is listed in the program 
http://codecombat.com/editor/level/sarven-savior.

The site will load the *level editor* for the Sarven Savior level, as shown.

For a different level go to http://codecombat.com/editor/level then type the level name in the "Search levels here bar" then click that level and follow picture instructions.

Once the site loads the level editor, click where the red arrows are in the following screenshots:

[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]
[image: step 3]
[image: step 4]

Comment: // , Congrats on finding an answer so quickly. Good first question.

Comment: // , Did you use Shutter for this?